# QT4 no such slot error

Tags: c++, netbeans, qt4, signals-slots

I know there are many many questions that are just the same, but none of them helps me:

```
class Form1 : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Form1();
    virtual ~Form1();
public slots:
    void langChange(const char* lang_label);
private:
    Ui::Form1 widget;
    void setLangStrings();
};
```

From1 constructor:

```
Form1::Form1() {
    widget.setupUi(this);
    connect(widget.btnL0, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(langChange("en")));
    connect(widget.btnL1, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(langChange("fr")));
    setLangStrings();
}
```

And I also have this langChange function implemented:

```
void Form1::langChange(const char* lang_label)
{
    GL_LANG = lang_label;
    setLangStrings();
}
```

**I get this stupid error when the connect function is called:**

```
No such slot Form1::langChange("sl") in Form1.cpp:15
```

I'm using NetBeans with QDesigner for the UI. I must say this QT4 is very difficult to learn.

Comment: You can not put a constant in a slot in a connect statement. So SLOT(langChange("en")) and SLOT(langChange("fr")) are both not going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can't connect SIGNAL with bool as argument to SLOT with const char* as argument. To do this kind of stuff you have to use [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html). You have an example how to use it inside documentation. In your case, it's very simple, so you should handle it easly.

Comment: I did it with two functions, one for each button. SIGNAL and SLOT have no arguments now... and it compiles.. :) ... not sure if this is good programming tactic, what I did...

Answer (score 0):

The SLOT function must have the same signature than the SIGNAL function

**Edit:** From the official Qt documentation (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html):

> The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving
>   slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it
>   receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)

Comment: Actually, not. A slot can take less arguments than provided by the signal - but not the opposite way!